# What does SQLITE_IOERR_VNODE code 6922 mean?

Tags: macos, sqlite, filesystems

My application connects to an SQLite database on a network file system via a hard link in read-only mode and does `SELECT` queries. We upgraded macOS to 10.12 and the application started to fail with a general (useless) error code SQLITE_IOERR and extended error code SQLITE_IOERR_VNODE (6922).

I could not find documentation about it or where it is used in the source code of SQLite. The only interesting info related to SQLite in the stack trace was "/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib+00738138 darwinFileTrackEvent+00000058".

Comment: Looks like a bug in mac OS. http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/What-does-SQLITE-IOERR-VNODE-mean-td95250.html

Answer (score 4):

The author of SQLite says [here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/What-does-SQLITE-IOERR-VNODE-mean-td95250.html):

> SQLITE_IOERR_VNODE is an error code used by proprietary modifications
> to SQLite implemented by Apple for use on MacOS and iOS.  I am told
> "The code indicates that a file relevant to the call was invalidated
> by a dispatch vnode source event" but I do not understand what that
> means.

and that thread contains further information and speculation about what might be causing the error.

An Apple WWDC talk in 2016 Session 242 "What's New in Core Data" slide 184 ([pdf here](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/242vdhuk4hmwrxnb465/242/242_whats_new_in_core_data.pdf)) says:

> What's New in SQLite
>
> SQLite now uses dispatch sources to track illegal file operations. API calls after illegal operations will return `SQLITE_IOERR_VNODE`

and references the SQLite page [howtocorrupt.html](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) and the setting `SQLITE_ENABLE_FILE_ASSERTIONS=1`. The [transcript of the talk](https://asciiwwdc.com/2016/sessions/242) accompanying that slide suggests:

> If you're using SQLite directly, you want to make sure that there's only one piece of code that owns that database and that code needs to go into the exclusive file access so files can't be changed when they're open.

#### My experience with this error

Prior to iOS 13 / Xcode 11, this happened rarely enough that I ignored it.

Now, with Xcode 11.2 and iOS 13, I typically see 5 failures out of 485 `XCTest` UI tests. The tests crash in SQLite with an extended error code of 6922 (while running the app in the simulator). There is no pattern to the crashes. Each time it is different tests. I've also seen it on my device with adhoc testing several times in a couple of days. Previously these automated tests (running on Xcode Server) had been quite stable.

Prior to this, I had seen this error occasionally in my iOS app both on a physical device and in the simulator when using Apple's provided SQLite library `libsqlite3.tbd`. In my scenario, the SQLite `.db` file is included in the (read-only) `.ipa` bundle. It is opened there directly as a read-only database and used lightly. It is hard to see how the code is "changing the file" (as suggested in the WWDC session). The first thread referenced above speculates that it might be related to memory-mapped file optimisation because vnodes are often used for that.

I have just completed adding the conveniently Xcode packaged SQLiteLib from https://github.com/swiftlyfalling/SQLiteLib. The tests are now running rock solid. In a few weeks I'll know if including SQLite statically has completely removed even the rare failures I used to get prior. (Update: the errors stopped happening, however I have since removed the SQLite file from my bundle completely so I don’t know what happens in later versions of iOS. Hopefully they have corrected what appears to be an erroneous error for both my scenerio and the original question, as they’re both read-only and not directly accessing the file in some other way).

#### TL;DR

Apple advocates using their OS-provided SQLite directly in iOS. It will detect file access errors that will be masked if you provide your own SQLite.

My personal experience with iOS 13 was that even if your code is sound (and accessing the database file read-only from the app bundle), this error can happen randomly. However, comments from @numist below suggest that this is a common use scenario should definitely work.  It seems that statically linking `sqlite` (using https://github.com/swiftlyfalling/SQLiteLib) masked this error for me with no consequences (other than a slight increase in app size). I have not tracked this problem beyond iOS 13 as I started using non-SQLite files for my bundled app data, and then later added SQLite CEROD support which required me to build SQLite directly. It quite possibly does not happen at all anymore (i.e. like iOS 12 and earlier).

Comment: Hi! I delivered that WWDC talk, so I'd like to be extra clear: you should definitely use the OS-provided SQLite, and you should never use filesystem operations on databases when they're open. The answer provided by user15435325 is exactly right.

Comment: @numist Thanks SO much for that extra info! Hmm, so this leaves me extra confused about my scenario where I was opening the file RO using SQLite from the iOS app bundle (which of course can ONLY be accessed read-only anyway). What other OS process could have been messing with my database file? (It wasn’t my code). I’d love any insights!  Point taken though that using a separate compiled SQLite is just masking a problem. Any clues on what else might have been accessing the file (or why iOS 13 made this crash more frequent with no code changes on my side)? Thanks for taking the time to comment!!

Comment: @numist I also adjusted my tldr conclusion based on your info. Hopefully it is more accurate now.

Comment: Your post is the first I've heard of people having this kind of problem shipping a read-only database in their bundle, and it's a pretty common pattern—as an example, the TED app has been doing it for a decade (meanwhile, databases vanishing due to NFS is extremely common). Assuming your bundled database uses delete mode journalling (wal databases do poorly with read-only environments), a Feedback Report with more details would be useful to investigate further.

Comment: @numist thanks again. I checked & I was opening the database with the SQLite RO parameter and no WAL parameter.  Unfortunately I never got a reliable repro. Nor have I gone back and used the iOS-provided SQLite since iOS 13 (bundling fixed it :) ). Since then, I've purchased SQLite's CEROD extension, so I need to build SQLite from source anyway. That said, this always intrigued me, so I'll log a Feedback Report if go that way again. Thanks for the followup & TED info.

Answer (score 4):

The error is the OS detecting that someone has performed an illegal file operation directly on your open database file out from underneath the SQLite API, which SQLite does not support and is a great way to corrupt your database as noted https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html. These errors are not specific to Core Data.  Whatever you are doing, the OSS SQLite library does not support it.

The recovery mechanism is as all SQLite I/O errors in which you are required to close the sqlite3* and open a new one.  You should be properly responding to all errors returned from sqlite APIs.

Statically linking a different sqlite library to suppress reporting of the error does not magically make SQLite support naked file operations out from underneath it.  It just ignores an error that is trying to tell you about a serious risk of file corruption.

There are a number of possible operations being detected including deleting the file out from underneath you, truncating the file out from underneath you, or unmounting the file system out from underneath you. If you want to do these operations safely, you need to close the sqlite database first.

Comment: Great info, thanks! Any idea what might be happening in the scenario where the file being accessed by SQLite is in the iOS app bundle itself? Ie it can only be read-only and thus cannot be being modified by other code? I’m confident my code was not trying to do so, so I can only speculate it was some iOS process and/or some error in this detection process. Thoughts on how I might track this down or prevent it - in this scenario of only accessing the database read-only from the app bundle? Thanks for such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

This error code is not used in the current version of the published SQLite library.

It appears this is used by Apple [for Core Data](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/242vdhuk4hmwrxnb465/242/242_whats_new_in_core_data.pdf):

> API calls after illegal operations will return SQLITE_IOERR_VNODE

Comment: Thanks for the link. We actually set the bit SQLITE_ENABLE_FILE_ASSERTIONS=1 to make the application crash and get the stack trace. Many possible causes are listed at https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html. Our database is in a network filesystem and connected in read-only mode. What "illegal operations" could be?